# Removing an object from array

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

Help with removing an object within an array after a collision is detected Actionscript 3. This is the code where problem is situated 
trace functions are in output according to the trace function with the exception of the last one.
Look: I am an amateur at this kind of thing. It's my first project and it needs to get done

```
trace("about to test bullet collisions");
for (var i:int = 0; i<bullets.length; i++) {
trace("bullet");trace(i);
for(var e2:int =0; e2<enemy.length; e2++){
    trace("enemy"); trace(e2);
    trace("bulletx"); trace(bullets[i].x);
   if (enemies[e2].hitTestObject(bullets[i].x, bullets[i].y, true)){
      trace("bullet collided with an enemy");
      removeChild(level.enemy);
      enemies.splice(e2, 1);
```

Comment: Removing an object while you are iterating an array is not a good idea. Set the index of the object you wish to remove, then remove it outside the loop

Comment: not really, if you modify the index of the array just make sure to iterate in reverse order. Which is anyway quicker iteration than forward. I'm using following template for backward loops:
`var i:int; for (i = HERE THE INITIAL VALUE; --i >= 0; ){/*here your actions*/}`

Comment: "with the exception of the last one" - you mean this: "trace("bullet collided with an enemy");"? Is there a chance that the bullets[i] doesn't contain the stage coordinates which hit test should get? From help: `The x and y parameters specify a point in the coordinate space of the Stage, not the display object container that contains the display object (unless that display object container is the Stage).`

Comment: are you trying to remove the enemy, the bullet, or both? also, does the `"bullet collided with an enemy"` trace fire?

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to remove an object from an Array from INSIDE a loop, it pays to iterate through the Array from highest index to lowest:

```
var arrayLength:int = _array.length;
for (var loop:int = arrayLength-1;loop>=0;loop--) {
    if (<conditional test to remove object here>) {
        _array.splice(loop, 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: I added this but I am still getting the same problem, the hit itself is not being detected

Comment: hitTestObject needs just one parameter - the other object you want to test for collision. It looks like you should be using hitTestPoint.

Answer (score 0):

It's the common problem when you iterate through the array and remove objects in this array that affects the length. Just decrease the iteration index by one after object removing:

```
if (enemies[e2].hitTestObject(bullets[i].x, bullets[i].y, true)){
   removeChild(level.enemy);
   enemies.splice(e2, 1);
   e2--
}
```

Comment: I do not understand how this will fix the problem of the object not disappearing.

Comment: does your code compile? you use _hitTestObject_ with signature (arguments number and types) from _hitTestPoint_

Comment: The program itself runs just the collision doesn't get detected

Comment: so try to change _hitTestObject_ to _hitTestPoint_

Comment: Doesnt matter if it's hitTestPoint or hitTestObject. Maybe the problem lies deeper than just this section of code? :/

Comment: I will just have to include in the test results reason why I couldn't add this enhancement :/ I do appreciate you help although I am sad that we couldn't reach a solution which suits my needs.